# C++Builder DrawGrid InsertControl not re-painting correctly after scrolling

Tags: c++builder

I am trying to add multiple controls to a drawgrid.  I can add the controls, but after adding them and scrolling, the control paint in different cells.

Here's the code I'm using to add the controls to my drawgrid:

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{

pnlHierBox = new TPanel(this);      //defined at the class level

```
pnlHierBox->Left = 0;
pnlHierBox->Top = 0;
pnlHierBox->Width = 180;
pnlHierBox->Height = 120;

img = new TImage(pnlHierBox);
img->Picture = Image1->Picture;
img->Left = 0;
img->Top = 3;
img->AutoSize = true;
img->Parent = pnlHierBox;

     lbl = new TLabel(pnlHierBox);
lbl->Caption = "Employee 1";
lbl->Left = 24;
lbl->Top= 15;
lbl->Parent = pnlHierBox;

icon = new TImage(pnlHierBox);
icon->Picture = Image2->Picture;
icon->Left = 100
icon->Top = 63;
icon->AutoSize = true;

icon->Parent = pnlHierBox;
rect = DrawGrid1->CellRect(2,0);
     pnlHierBox->Top = rect.Top;
     pnlHierBox->Left = rect.Left;

     DrawGrid1->InsertControl(pnlHierBox);
```

//   Add other TPanel controls to the drawgrid
//

}

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `InsertControl()` directly.  Use the `Parent` property instead:

```
// DrawGrid1->InsertControl(pnlHierBox);
pnlHierBox->Parent = DrawGrid1;
```

Comment: I took out the insertcontrol() and added the pnlHierBox->Parent = DrawGrid1; and still not painting. It's like the cells need to get invalidated or repainted and they are not. Works fine is I just use OnDrawCell and draw the images in the cells. I just wanted to be able to have controls so I could get events when clicked etc. 

Any other ideas?  Appreciate any help.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry.. Did mention your name @Remy Lebeau - TeamB

Comment: The VCL's stock grid controls ARE NOT designed to support embedded controls (other than their built-in `InplaceEdit` control).  It takes a lot of manual work to embed controls and keep them in sync.  You are best of just using the `OnDrawCell` event and simulate the UI behavior you need.